# Set-PSDebug -Trace 2 is causing my powershell code to throw an error that doesn't occur without tracing on

Tags: powershell

Imagine a script `test.ps1` that looks like this:

```
Param (
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $VMHost,

    [switch]
    $trace
)

$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
Set-StrictMode -Version 2

trap {
    Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
    $_.InvocationInfo
    break
}

if ($trace) {
    Set-PSDebug -Trace 2
}

if ($VMHost) {
    $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | % {
        $h = $_
        Switch ($h.GetType().Name) {
            'String' {
                "isastring"
            }
            default {
                Write-Error -Category InvalidType -TargetObject $h -ErrorAction Stop -Message 'VMHost argument must be a String or a VMHost object.'
            }
        }
    })
}
```

When run normally it does this:

```
PS> & .\test.ps1 -VMHost "foo"
foo
```

When run with the `-trace` argument however it does this:

```
PS> & .\test.ps1 -VMHost "foo" -trace
DEBUG:   21+ if ( >>>> $VMHost) {
DEBUG:   22+      >>>> $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | % {
DEBUG:   22+     $VMHost = @( >>>> @($VMHost) | % {
DEBUG:   22+     $VMHost = @(@( >>>> $VMHost) | % {
DEBUG:   22+     $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | %  >>>> {
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock>'  (defined in file 'path...\test.ps1')
DEBUG:   23+          >>>> $h = $_
DEBUG:     ! SET $h = 'foo'.
DEBUG:     ! SET $switch = 'String'.
DEBUG:   24+         Switch ( >>>> $h.GetType().Name) {
DEBUG:     ! SET $switch = ''.
DEBUG:   35+      >>>> })
DEBUG:     ! SET $VMHost = ''.
DEBUG:   13+      >>>> Set-PSDebug -Trace 0
DEBUG:     ! CALL function '<ScriptBlock><trap>'  (defined in file
'path...\test.ps1')


MyCommand             :
BoundParameters       : {}
UnboundArguments      : {}
ScriptLineNumber      : 23
OffsetInLine          : 19
HistoryId             : -1
ScriptName            : path...\test.ps1
Line                  :     $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | % {

PositionMessage       : At path...\test.ps1:23 char:19
                        +     $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | % {
                        +                   ~~~~~~~
PSScriptRoot          : C:\Users\ereisner\TenableAppliancePackaging
PSCommandPath         : C:\Users\ereisner\TenableAppliancePackaging\test.ps1
InvocationName        :
PipelineLength        : 0
PipelinePosition      : 0
ExpectingInput        : False
CommandOrigin         : Internal
DisplayScriptPosition :

The variable cannot be validated because the value System.Object[] is not a valid value for the VMHost variable.
At path...\test.ps1:22 char:19
+     $VMHost = @(@($VMHost) | % {
+                   ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValidateSetFailure
```

How is trace debugging causing an error like this?

What is powershell doing here?

Can this filter/assignment be cleanly rewritten to avoid this problem (bug?)?

Powershell version info:

```
PS> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      3.0
WSManStackVersion              3.0
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
BuildVersion                   6.2.9200.16481
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.2
```

Comment: My guess is that: problem caused by that line: `! SET $switch = 'String'.`. On my PC (PowerShell v5) it is `! SET $switch = 'IEnumerator'.`. How PowerShell will know that that enumerator contains string `String` without enumerating it? And if PowerShell already enumerate it to display its value, than what is left for `switch` loop to enumerate? Some kind of PowerShell quantum effect, by observing variable, you change its value. You can try something like this: `switch(1..10){default{$_}}`.

Comment: @PetSerAl I wonder why you are seeing an enumerator there at all. The `%` should be operating on the elements in the array which should be a single string at that point as I understand things. What do you see for the assignment in `@("foo") | % { $h = $_ }` with tracing on in v5? Also try `-vmhost "foo","bar"` and see what you get?

Comment: The error appears to be that PS is running off the end of the array for some reason. See how it loops *twice* for an array of one element?

Comment: `%` not relevant here at all. `switch` is a loop and `$switch` is an automatic variable, which set to `IEnumerator` for a `switch` loop. `$switch` is set even if you use `switch($SingleValue){...}`. Try that `switch(1..10){default{$_}}` under trace mode in PowerShell v3.

Comment: @PetSerAl I have an array of strings (and possibly vmhost objects). I want to loop over the array converting the strings to vmhost objects. I was using a `switch` (in the `%` loop) to do the testing. This is breaking with tracing on. The fact that `switch` is itself a loop shouldn't be an issue. I'm passing `switch` a single string. It shouldn't loop over anything... but it seems like it is. That's the question. Why is it doing that? What is going wrong? If you can think of a better way to do what I'm trying to do I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer but it appears that this is a powershell version 3 bug.

The issue appears to be in how `switch` behaves in this scenario. It appears to "loop" one past the end of the single string argument it is given.

The same code run under PS 4 works as expected.